# Sanity- Next.js real time updating content

Tags: next.js, real-time, sanity

I am making a social media app with next.js and sanity as cms. I want a feature that if someone on other computer likes a post, it gets automatically live updated at someone else screen, just like twitter

I saw that sanity supports live update, but I can't understand its docs.

For example, I like a post here, it will mutate the main post document, which will trigger the real time update system and then that trigget will be caught at all other screens and content will get updated! ( if you can understand what I am trying to say.)

Please suggest a code for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to listen to queries:

https://www.sanity.io/docs/js-client#listening-to-queries

```js
const query = '*[_type == "comment" && authorId != $ownerId]'
const params = {ownerId: 'bikeOwnerUserId'}

const subscription = client.listen(query, params).subscribe((update) => {
  const comment = update.result
  console.log(`${comment.author} commented: ${comment.text}`)
})

// to unsubscribe later on
subscription.unsubscribe()
```